# Video lectures for studying graduate level kinetic theory

Tags: statistical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, kinetic-theory

As the title says it all, I require Video lectures for studying graduate level kinetic theory including but not limited to detailed **analysis** of **viscosity and conductivity**, **diffusion** and **Maxwell's Velocity Distribution**.

N.B. *I've looked everywhere, but no luck yet*

Comment: I assume you have looked at the lectures that MIT (I think other universities are doing this as well) posts on YouTube?

Comment: Yeah they have a collection on Statistical Mechanics, that deals with a bit of KT. But the lectures lack almost all the highlighted topics that I mentioned.